# How to insert values in store in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

i am implementing project in extjs. i am very new to extjs.
i had created view with two Textfields Question and Option and also created two buttons as ok and cancel.

My view code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Question-option',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Question',
        fieldLabel: 'Question',
        allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Option',
        fieldLabel: 'Option',
        vtype: 'Option'  // requires value to be a valid email address format
    },
    {xtype: 'button', text: 'Ok'}, 
    {xtype: 'button', text: 'Cancel'}
 ]
});
```

On ok button click i want to add these textfields data into store.

So can you please suggest me how to write buttonclick event to add all these textfields data into store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take this store as example:

```
Ext.define ('model', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model' ,
  fields: ['Question', 'Option']
});

var store = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'model'
});

// Handler called on button click event
function handler (button) {
  var form = button.up('form').getForm ();

  // Validate the form
  if (form.isValid ()) {
    var values = form.getFieldValues ();
    store.add ({
      Question: values.Question ,
      Option: values.Option
    });
  }
  else {} // do something else here
}
```

You get the form data and then add those data to the store.

Cyaz

Comment: Thanx for your reply.And If i also want to add those inserted Question and its Option in gridview and need to make that option input field as blank textbox in order to add more options for same question.And display all these inserted options in gridview. So in what way i should di this?

Comment: Just attach the store to a grid panel.
For instance: Ext.create ('Ext.grid.Panel', {title: 'MyGrid', width: 300, height: 300, store: store, columns: [{name: 'Question', dataIndex: 'Question'} , {name: 'Option', dataIndex: 'Option'}]});
If you've found this answer the correct one, please make it ;)

Comment: when i am inserting above onbuttonclick event,view is not getting display.controller code is-Ext.define('AM.controller.Users',{
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller', views:['user.List']
  store: ['Users'] model: ['User'],  
        init: function() {
     this.control({
         "button": {
             click: Ext.msg.alert("Heloo") }});}
onButtonClick: function(button){ var form =button.up('form').getForm ();

if (form.isValid ()) {
     var values = form.getFieldValues ();
     store.add ({
       Question: values.Question ,
       Option: values.Option
     });
   }
    }});